# How to extract elements from string as xml and return part of the element's value

Tags: c#, xml

I am planning on extracting the id based on the message, the id holds, in a log file. For eg: if the message is "Application started", i should associate the id for the message and return in an inenumerable list.

Here is my xml string:

```
String xml =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<log>\n" +
            "    <entry id=\"1\">\n" +
            "        <message>Application started</message>\n" +
            "    </entry>\n" +
            "    <entry id=\"2\">\n" +
            "        <message>Application ended</message>\n" +
            "    </entry>\n" +
            "</log>";
```

And in my main method, I am calling the GetIDsByMessage to read through the string :

```
foreach (int id in LogParser.GetIdsByMessage(xml, "Application ended"))
        Console.WriteLine(id);
```

And i am defining my GetIdsByMessage as :

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIdsByMessage(string xml, string message)
{
     // write to return id {2} for message="Application ended"
}
```

I tried parsing the string as xml like this:

```
 XmlDocument xmltest = new XmlDocument();
 xmltest.LoadXml(xml);

 XmlNodeList elemlist = xmltest.GetElementsByTagName("message");
```

But I am not sure how to collect all the ids and return it back to the caller.  Any pointers ?

Here's my full code:

```
 public class LogParser
    {
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetIdsByMessage(string xml, string message)
    {
         // write to return id {2} for message="Application ended"
         XmlDocument xmltest = new XmlDocument();
         xmltest.LoadXml(xml);

         XmlNodeList elemlist = xmltest.GetElementsByTagName("message");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<log>\n" +
                "    <entry id=\"1\">\n" +
                "        <message>Application started</message>\n" +
                "    </entry>\n" +
                "    <entry id=\"2\">\n" +
                "        <message>Application ended</message>\n" +
                "    </entry>\n" +
                "</log>";

        foreach (int id in LogParser.GetIdsByMessage(xml, "Application ended"))
            Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This works: `XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Descendants("message").Where(x => x.Value == "Application ended").Select(x => x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value)`

Comment: @Enigmativity I guess you could put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily use Linq-to-XML:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIdsByMessage(string xml, string message) =>
    XDocument
        .Parse(xml)
        .Root
        .Descendants("message")
        .Where(x => x.Value == message)
        .Select(x => (int)x.Parent.Attribute("id"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity, that solved my issue, need to learn a lot on xml & LinqToSql.